# Why clusterAnnotationForMemberAnnotations in MKMapView is not called?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I have a simple map view:

```
@IBOutlet private var mapView: MKMapView!
```

Then one by one I add annotations:

```
mapView.addAnnotation(Annotation(user: user))
```

and show them all:

```
mapView.showAnnotations(mapView.annotations, animated: true)
```

I also implemented the method:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, clusterAnnotationForMemberAnnotations memberAnnotations: [MKAnnotation]) -> MKClusterAnnotation {
    print(memberAnnotations)
    return MKClusterAnnotation(memberAnnotations: memberAnnotations)
}
```

but this is not called at all. Why?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Noticed the same today in the iOS 11.2 simulator. Declared that the containing class is the delegate but it simply doesn't appear to work..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears as though it is required to set the `clusteringIdentifier` for the MKAnnotationView. This has worked for me:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier, for: annotation)
    annotationView.clusteringIdentifier = "identifier"
    return annotationView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check

```
class YourViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
```

and

```
mapView.delegate = self
```

See also: https://github.com/artemnovichkov/iOS-11-by-Examples/blob/master/iOS-11-by-Examples/MapKit/MapKitViewController.swift

Answer (score 0):

@peter's answer worked for me, but I find it more intuitive to set the clusterIdentifier directly on your MKAnnotationView instead of using a delegate method to set it in. For example:

```
class VehicleAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {
    override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
        willSet {
            clusteringIdentifier = "1"

            canShowCallout = true
            calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)
            rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)

            image = UIImage(named: "MapVehiclePin")

        }
    }
}
```