# MapKit: calloutAccessoryControlTapped not called for cluster

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

[Workaround is found, see first comments]

This is iOS 11:

on my mapView I have some annotations

```
class POIView: MKMarkerAnnotationView {
static let REUSEIDENTIFIER = "POIView"

override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
    willSet {
        guard let poi = newValue as? POI else { return }
        canShowCallout = true
        calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)

        let rightCalloutButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
        let rightCalloutImage = UIImage(named: "loc-map-route-line-tab")
        rightCalloutButton.setImage(rightCalloutImage, for: .normal)
        rightCalloutButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: rightCalloutImage?.size.width ?? 0, height: rightCalloutImage?.size.height ?? 0)
        rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightCalloutButton
        // some more code
        clusteringIdentifier = String(describing: POIView.self)
    }
}

}
```

This works fine, annotations and callout are shown on the map.
When I tap on the rightCalloutAccessoryView button, the correct delegate method is called:

```
public func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView,
                    calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
...
}
```

I also have a cluster view:

```
internal final class POIClusterView: MKAnnotationView {
static let REUSEIDENTIFIER = "POIClusterView"

override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
    willSet {
        if let cluster = newValue as? MKClusterAnnotation {
            canShowCallout = true
            let rightCalloutButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
            let rightCalloutImage = UIImage(named: "loc-map-route-line-tab")
            rightCalloutButton.setImage(rightCalloutImage, for: .normal)
            rightCalloutButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: rightCalloutImage?.size.width ?? 0, height: rightCalloutImage?.size.height ?? 0)
            rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightCalloutButton
            ...
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

It works fine, it shows the callout, the callout shows a button on the right side.
But when I tap on the right button of the cluster callout, the aforementioned method

```
public func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView,
                    calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
...
}
```

is not called.

What do I have to do to detect a tap on the cluster callout right button?

Comment: I don't think you can use same delegate for cluster. At least I never saw this approach. The method is waiting an `MKAnnotationView` and you're passing a `MKClusterAnnotation`. I will have a look on this approach but you can attach a target to your button as a work around.

Comment: @GIJOW Your workaround sounds good.

Comment: @GIJOW Your workaround works fine, thanks

Comment: Glad to hear that. About your issue, the closest I got is this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47914910/why-clusterannotationformemberannotations-in-mkmapview-is-not-called/47926765 the last answer maybe can help. Cheers

Comment: @GIJOW this is what I'm already doing. It is not called.